# Fill fields using value from another subquery in a LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following Linq, Can i use LINQ like this to get values for **IsPremiumUser** and **IsLawFirm** on the go or is there is any other good way to do this?

What i need is to get the values of **IsPremiumUser** and **IsLawFirm** based on their supplier id. I dont want to add any foreach to do this work, can i use LINQ to get these values

```
var supplierListQuery = 
    (from sup in db.PPSuppliers
     select new SearchResultSupplierViewModel
     {
         SupplierId = sup.PPSupplierId,
         SupplierLocation = sup.LocationsForDisplay,
         CreatedDate = (DateTime)sup.CreatedDate,
         PPMemberId = sup.PPMemberId,
         IsPremiumUser =
             (from u in db.PPSubscriptions
              join s in db.PPSubscriptionPlans on u.SubscriptionPlanId equals s.SubscriptionPlanId
              where u.PPMemberId == sup.PPMemberId && u.SubscriptionEndDate >= System.DateTime.Now
              orderby u.SubscriptionStartDate descending
              select s).FirstOrDefault().isPremium,
         IsLawFirm = 
             (from l in db.PPSupplierSupplierTypes 
              join f in db.PPSupplierTypes on l.PPSupplierTypeId equals f.PPSupplierTypeId
              where l.PPSupplierId == sup.PPSupplierId && f.PPSupplierTypeId == 1
              select l).Any()
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put a profiler to see what SQL EF is generating then i would make a decision: If the query seems veeeery complicated and could generate performance issues, then I would try to do other things:

- use "let" keyword
- try to load subqueries data in intermediate data structures that are simmilar with a hashtable that has on key the PPSuppliers Id and on value, whatever data you need to distribute, then with a single foreach loop over suppliers i would peek from these intermediate structures in O ( 1) what additional informations i need to add.
- use a stored procedure :)